# WebPushError: Received unexpected response code - GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, web-push, progressive-web-apps

I am using web push to enable push notifications for app.

webPush.setGCMAPIKey('my-gcm-api-key');

```
app.post('/sendNotification', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body)
      payloads[req.body.endpoint] = req.body.payload;
      webPush.sendNotification(req.body.endpoint
       , {
         TTL: req.body.ttl,
       }
      )
      .then(function() {
          console.log('mest')
        res.sendStatus(201);
      })
      .catch(function(err){
          console.log(err)
      });
  });
```

I am getting below error during the sendNotification api call.

```
{ [WebPushError: Received unexpected response code]
  name: 'WebPushError',
  message: 'Received unexpected response code',
  statusCode: 400,
  headers:
   { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
     date: 'Thu, 22 Sep 2016 09:22:31 GMT',
     expires: 'Thu, 22 Sep 2016 09:22:31 GMT',
     'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
     server: 'GSE',
     'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34,33,32"',
     'accept-ranges': 'none',
     vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
     connection: 'close' },
  body: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>UnauthorizedRegistration</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>UnauthorizedRegistration</H1>\n<H2>Error 400</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n' }
```

Please let me know if anyone came across this issue.

Comment: Have you activated your account on Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: yes. i missed the below auth options
 userPublicKey: req.body.key,
userAuth: req.body.authSecret, . now it is working